# OpenSubKey not working for Registry value I need

Tags: c#

I have SQL Server installed.

In the registry, the key **MSSQLServer** at *HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft* looks like this:
[image]

All of the following lines of code return values from the registry:

```
    var mainKey = Microsoft.Win32.Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey("SOFTWARE").OpenSubKey("Microsoft").OpenSubKey("MSSQLServer");
    var subKey1 = Microsoft.Win32.Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey("SOFTWARE").OpenSubKey("Microsoft").OpenSubKey("MSSQLServer").OpenSubKey("Client");
    var subKey2 = Microsoft.Win32.Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey("SOFTWARE").OpenSubKey("Microsoft").OpenSubKey("MSSQLServer").OpenSubKey("MSSQLServer").OpenSubKey("CurrentVersion");
```

However, this one does not:

```
var subKey3 = Microsoft.Win32.Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey("SOFTWARE").OpenSubKey("Microsoft").OpenSubKey("MSSQLServer").OpenSubKey("Setup");
```

"Setup" looks to be the same type of value as the other keys.  Any thoughts why this command returns null?

Comment: Do you have the necessary permissions to read that key? The application that is running the code, I mean. Try to run as administrator and see it if opens

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Your application is 32-bit and that is a 64-bit registry key. 32-bit and 64-bit applications have different views of the registry. In regedit the key you are getting in code is at HKLM\Software\Wow6432Node\MSSQLServer, not HKLM\Software\MSSQLServer (in your picture).

Unfortunately, the managed [API](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Application_programming_interface) for accessing registry keys does not allow a 32-bit application to get a 64-bit view of the registry.

There are two options: Change your application to target AnyCPU or x64 or [P/Invoke](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Platform_Invocation_Services) the unmanaged API. [This](http://geekswithblogs.net/derekf/archive/2007/06/26/113485.aspx) has an example of how to do the P/Invoke and the [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa384129%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) documentation.

BTW, you can pass a path to the OpenSubKey method instead of chaining them together like that.

**Update**: I was not quite correct above. As of .NET 4, the `OpenBaseKey` method ([MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.win32.registrykey.openbasekey.aspx)) can be used to get a 64-bit view in a 32-bit application.

Comment: I have been trying to work on a similar issue for the past 2 hours. This guided me to rebuild my project in Visual Studio as 64-bit, and now I can find the application I wanted to verify installation for. God send!