# C# FileNotFoundException on Application startup

Tags: c#, .net, windows

I have problem with my app.
When i run it by myself all works perfect.
But when my app start from startup I have System.IO.FileNotFoundException.
I add my app on startup by following code:

```
RegistryKey wowNode = Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey("SOFTWARE\\Wow6432Node\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\Run", true);

wowNode.SetValue("myApp", System.Reflection.Assembly.GetEntryAssembly().Location);
```

and when my app start after reboot I have System.IO.FileNotFoundException
all files are in the same directory with .exe file

Can someone help me with this?

code I use for read file:

```
names = File.ReadAllLines("name.txt");
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [OpenSubKey not working for Registry value I need](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10918877/opensubkey-not-working-for-registry-value-i-need)

Answer (score 0):

When started as startup, the current directory is not set to that where the .exe resides. So use [`Application.ExecutablePath`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.application.executablepath%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to get the directory in which your app resides and use that as a suffix to "name.txt" to get it's true path.